# select count(*) query is too slow. I'm guess it is not work by indexing

Tags: mysql, linux, centos5, mysql5

I would like to ask for comment because I did a better search.

My server environment is below.

- CentOS release 5.1
- Linux 2.6,18
- CPU: Intel (R) Xeon (R) CPU E3-1230 v3 @ 3.30GHz 8core
- M / M: 8 GB
- MySQL v5.5.40

There are about 260,000 records in this table (kc_article-MyISAM).

```
 mysql> desc kc_article;

+ --------------------- + ---------------------- + ---- -+ ----- + --------------------- + ---------------- +

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |

+ --------------------- + ---------------------- + ---- -+ ----- + --------------------- + ---------------- +

| idx | int (11) | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |

| w_status | tinyint (4) | NO | MUL | 1 | |

| w_subj | varchar (255) | NO | MUL | NULL | |

~~ omission ~~

| w_section1 | int (11) | NO | MUL | NULL | |

| w_section2 | int (11) | NO | MUL | NULL | |

| w_theme | int (11) | NO | MUL | NULL | |

~~ Lay ~~
```

Even though the index is created in the query condition, the speed sometimes goes beyond 1, 2, 10, or 20 seconds.
w_status and w_section2 are both indexed.

```
mysql> explain select count (*) as cnt from kc_article
       where w_status> 5
         and (w_section2 = '68')
```

```
+ ---- + ------------- + ------------ + ------ + ---------- ----------- + ------------ + --------- + ------- + ------- + ------------- +

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |

+ ---- + ------------- + ------------ + ------ + ---------- ----------- + ------------ + --------- + ------- + ------- + ------------- +

| 1 | SIMPLE | kc_article | ref | w_section2, w_status | w_section2 | 4 | const | 33548 | Using where |

+ ---- + ------------- + ------------ + ------ + ---------- ----------- + ------------ + --------- + ------- + ------- + ------------- +
```

The same is true for checking, restoring, and optimizing the table and recreating it after dropping the index.
The value of w_status is an integer from 0 to 6, with 6 being 95% or more.

I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: What are the actual indices setup on the `kc_article` table?

Comment: You don't show any index in the question. The query doesn't use the primary key, the only column that's actually indexed. The phrase `the index is created in the query condition` is weird: indexes are *used* by queries, they aren't created by them. Indexes have to be explicitly created when creating or altering a table.

Comment: BTW MySQL 5.5 is extremely old. You may be running into problems fixed into later versions. 260K isn't a lot of data, it's actually rather smallish. Perhaps there's contention with other connections that try to access the same table? If you have a lot of UPDATEs or INSERTs going on, a `SELECT` that scans the entire table will be blocked by every one of them. 20 seconds may be the time needed for MySQL to lock all rows to calculate the count. Indexing will reduce blocking too

Comment: Please confirm the helpfulness of GMB's answer after your tests are completed.  We see you can not upvote or Accept answers with this new logon.  Welcome to stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

To start with, this query:

```
select count (*) as cnt from kc_article where w_status> 5 and (w_section2 = '68')
```

Should be written as:

```
select count (*) as cnt from kc_article where w_status =  and w_section2 = 68
```

Parentheses are superfluous, and since `w_section2` is an integer it should be compared     against an integer, not a string. Also, `w_status` ranges from 0 to 6, so you can use an equality condition instead of an inequality.

You mentionned that *w_status and w_section2 are both indexed*. For this query, you want a compound index on both columns, not an index on each column (otherwise, MySQL cannot use both at the same time). If it does not exist, then create it:

```
create index kc_article_status_section_idx on kc_article(w_status, w_section2);
```

A few hundred thousand rows is not a big dataset, I would expect that your query should run fast with the above index.

Comment: Your response has been helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

select count (1) as cnt from kc_article where w_status> 5 and w_section2 = '68'

Comment: `COUNT(1)` and `COUNT(*)` are performed the same way.  `COUNT(col)`  is different in that it counts only when `col` is not `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

This composite index, *in this order* is what you need:

```
INDEX(w_secdion2, w_status)
```

When building an index, *start* with the `=` clauses.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql